# Norm of $n \times n \times n$ Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Given a real positive semi definite matrix, $A\in R^{n\times n}$  and a real matrix $F \in R^{b\times n }$, we have the following inequality:

$\|FAF^T\| \le \|FF^T\| \|A\|$.

However, I am wondering about the situation when A is a $n \times n \times n$ tensor.

Is there a similar inequality? If so, what is the norm of a tensor?